# read comment as a space by getchar

Tags: c

I am making program counting letters and words by getchar and switch.
But I don't know how to read */ /* comment as a space. Since * and / are read respectively by getchar, So I can't have a progress in reading */  by getchar.
Please help me.

Comment: Are you asking how to handle the fact that the comment marker is two characters?  If so, consider keeping track of the character read by `getchar` on the previous pass of the loop.  If not, I'm afraid your question will need some clarification.

Comment: There are a number of questions on SO about how to read C comments.  The full details are nauseatingly complicated — backslashes at the ends of lines complicate things enormously, and so do trigraphs.  However, you can probably ignore such niceties — they're issues a compiler writer has to deal with, but not someone working on a program for a course exercise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, and about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) more urgently.  You should show what you currently have, and explain where you're having problems making it work the way you need it to.  That also allows us to place your familiarity with C, so we can suggest appropriate solutions.